# React.js Component Child - Global interaction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Component child in React.js

I am creating an app which can be seen as a crypto-portfolio list. Every coin item has some details like holdings and price. These are saved in a dictionary saved in localstorage and loaded in the portfolio container components' state.

The hierarchy can be seen as Container > PortfolioList > Portfolio Item.

My question is as follows: onClick of the Portfolio Item, I want to populate an entirely different component with an API call of that Portfolio Coin ( to show an historical graph ), called PortfolioDetails.

### Question

How is this component - global interaction best handled in React.js? Is it best practice to define a state in the PortfolioContainer and change it upon clicking on the PortfolioItem child (passing it through 2 parents), or is there a way to re-render the PortfolioDetails component onClick, like I tried here?

Thank you!

```
export default class PortfolioContainer extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = (
        {portfolio:
          {ICX:{transactions:[{purchase: '$49.99', amount: 50}], price:{raw:{BTC:{PRICE:3.20}}, display:{BTC:{PRICE:3.20}}}},
        currency: 'BTC',
        total: 0
        }
    )
}

render(){

    return(
        <Container>
            <Row>
                <Col xs="12">
                    <PortfolioList currency={this.state.currency} portfolio={this.state.portfolio} />
                    <PortfolioDetails show='portfolio'/>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </Container>
    );
}
}    


export class PortfolioList extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}



render(){
    const rows = [];

    if(Object.keys(this.props.portfolio).length > 0){
        Object.keys(this.props.portfolio).map((coin, details) =>{

            rows.push(
                <CoinRow
                coin={coin}
                details={this.props.portfolio[coin]}
                currency={this.props.currency}
                key={coin}
                />
            )
        });
    }
    return(
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Coin</th>
                    <th>Holdings</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
}

export class CoinRow extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
}

handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get coin ID from clicked event
    var coinId = e.currentTarget.attributes['data-id'].value;
    // Populate portfolio details with coin details
    <PortfolioDetails show={coinId}/>

}

render(){
    const coin = this.props.coin;
    const details = this.props.details;
    var holdings = null;
    return (
        <tr data-id={coin} onClick={this.handleClick}>
            <td>{coin}</td>
            <td>{holdings}</td>
            <td>{details.price.display[this.props.currency].PRICE}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}
} 
export class PortfolioDetails extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}


render(){
    var showing = this.props.show;
    return(
        <div>
            // Showing details for the following coin
            <p>{showing}</p>
        </div>
        );
}
}
```

Comment: You should use Redux, e.g. https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do what you want is using `Redux`.

This way you would have a flow like this:

[image: redux flow]

Can you see that the `UI` is defined by the `State` and there is a unique `Store` that contains the application `State`? That's why Redux works nicely in your use case.

You can keep a `State` in your `Store` like:

```
cryptoPorfolio: { // this is the name of the reducer, it will be part of the state tree, read below
  coin: ''
}
```

Now you can update this `State` firing an action in the 'UI', that will be sent to the `Reducer` that finally makes the update. Something like this:

**Action**

```
{
  type: 'UPDATE_COIN',
  coinName: 'ETH'
}
```

**Action Creator** (just functions that can be triggered by the UI)

```
function updateCoin(coin) {
    return {
      type: 'UPDATE_COIN',
      coinName: 'Ethereum'
    }
}
```

You can use [bindActionCreators](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/bindactioncreators) from `react-redux` to pass your action creator to your component.

Then, in your Component, you would call this action creator like a normal function passed as a prop in order to send an action to the reducer.

Finally, in the reducer, you can update the `Store`. For example:

```
function cryptoPorfolio(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_COIN:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        coin: action.coinName
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

For more detailed info, read [Redux usage with React](https://redux.js.org/basics/usage-with-react).

Comment: You are right, Redux is perfect for this. To add to the answer, the following article serves as a great tutorial if anyone is interested! https://hackernoon.com/a-basic-react-redux-introductory-tutorial-adcc681eeb5e

Answer (score 1):

Yes the best practice would be to have the `PortfolioContainer` manage the state of what children are hidden/shown. That would be the easiest way to get the whole component tree to update. You can have a `handlePortfolioItemClick` method on there, which can update the state to show the different data inside `PortfolioDetails`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What is your opinion on using Redux in this case like Tiago Alves suggests? To me your answer seems easier (but a bit hacky), but is it better practice to use Redux in this case?

Comment: Sure Redux is great, but React is great without Redux too. If your application state is big and complex, then I would definitely recommend using something like Redux to manage it. But if you're just making something simple, then I don't think there is a need to add the overhead. This article written by the creator of Redux gives a good outline of when to use and when not to use it: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367